# How to return input variables to main function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, return

I attempting to make a program that allows the user to customize the U.S flag, though I've hit a snag. I want to return the `flagHeight`, `flagWidth`, and `starArea` variables back to the `main()` function, so they can be used in the output `for` statement.

My goal is to have two functions; the `main()` function where that output will be displayed, and a second function that takes the user input.

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double input_Flag();
    
double input_Flag()
{
    double flagWidth;
    double flagHeight;
    double starArea;
    
    int restriction_1 = 5;
    int restriciton_2 = 70;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the flag width you would like (between 5 <--> 70): ";
        cin >> flagWidth;
        cout << endl;
        if (flagWidth >= restriction_1 and flagWidth <= restriciton_2)
        {
            cout << "Your width is |" << flagWidth << "|";
            cout << endl;
            continue;
        }

    } while (flagWidth < restriction_1 or flagWidth > restriciton_2);

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the flag height (between 5 <--> " << flagWidth << "): ";
        cin >> flagHeight;
        cout << endl;
        if (flagHeight >= restriction_1 and flagHeight <= flagWidth)
        {
            cout << "Your height is |" << flagHeight << "|";
            cout << endl;
            continue;
        }

    } while (restriction_1 > flagHeight or flagWidth < flagHeight);

    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the star area (area < " << flagHeight << "):";
        cin>>starArea;
        cout << endl;
        if (starArea < flagHeight)
        {
            cout << "Your star area of the flag is |" << starArea << "|";
            cout << endl;
            continue;
        }

    } while (1 > starArea or starArea >= flagHeight);
}

void myPause()
{
    cout << "[Press ENTER to see your flag]";
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome! Customize Your Flag below!" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    input_Flag();
    cout << endl;

    myPause();
    cout << endl;

    for(int x = 1; x <= flagHeight; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 1; y <= flagWidth; y++)
        {
            if(x <= starArea and y <= starArea)
                cout << "*";
            else
                cout << "=";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "Awesome flag!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lookup _reference parameters_ regarding that.

Comment: you can define a method in c++ that can actually modify the values you give as parameter even after the return... as @πάνταῥεῖ said, lookup for reference parameters

Comment: There are two ways to return multiple variables from a function: 1) passing individual parameters by reference/pointer, or 2) `return`'ing a `struct`/`class`/`std::tuple` (or passing one as a reference/pointer parameter)